# Google Play - migrating from APK to AAB - staged rollout does not work

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

We have an Android app built in 2020, we regularly update it by generating and uploading APKs. We always start with staged rollout (50% of audience etc.) in case something goes wrong and we can rollback everything.

Now we created AAB instead of APK, uploaded it, got approved, and started staged rollout (99% of audience). However, Play Store keeps suggesting old version to users *(new users keep installing old version, old users keep using old version and 0 people have upgraded. We see this from stats)*

We have lots of traffic (50k installs daily), so we would definitely notice if someone upgraded.

Why is that? Has anybody encountered this? It seems to me that partial rollout does not work while upgrading from APK to AAB, am I right?

Comment: When you open the release track, does the AAB version have a higher version code?

Comment: We have faced this issue in one of our apps where the update was rolled out but few devices didn't receive that and the old app is still showing there however we have published multiple apps but the issue has not resolved and we wrote back to google but they responded that it will take some time but after 6 months still devices didn't get the update and those are latest devices like Samsung S20+ having android 12. 
It looks like this is a rollout issue with the play store that need to handle by Google.